# How to reassign struct fields with a method?

Tags: rust

I want to re-assign a value of a structs field. The following code compiles, but returns an empty instance with the dbg! macro.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Point {
    x: u8,
    y: u8,
}
impl Point {
    pub fn new (x: u8, y: u8) -> Self {
        Self {x, y}
    }
    pub fn add_to_x(&mut self, by: u8) {
        self.x = self.x + by
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut val = Point::new(5, 8);
    let val = val.add_to_x(5);
    dbg!(val)
}
```

How can I do this successfully? I know how to return a Self instance but I would like to do it partially, just for some fields.

Comment: Remove the `let val = `, since `val.add_to_x(5)` mutates `val` in-place and returns unit.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a new variable:

```rs
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Point {
    x: u8,
    y: u8,
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new (x: u8, y: u8) -> Self {
        Self {x, y}
    }
    pub fn add_to_x(&mut self, by: u8) {
        self.x = self.x + by
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut val = Point::new(5, 8);
    val.add_to_x(5);
    dbg!(val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let val = val.add_to_x(5); //Shadows the original val and is empty
dbg!(val)
```

As suggested by others, the following will work.

```
val.add_to_x(5);
dbg!(val);
```

Or you could modify `add_to_x` to return `Self`

Answer (score 2):

The core problem is that your method doesn't return `u8` it returns `()` because the expression `self.x = self.x + by` doesn't return `self.x`, it's `()`.

Here's what you *probably* wanted to do:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Point {
    x: u8,
    y: u8,
}
impl Point {
    pub fn new (x: u8, y: u8) -> Self {
        Self {x, y}
    }
    pub fn add_to_x(&mut self, by: u8) -> u8 {
        self.x = self.x + by;
        self.x
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut val = Point::new(5, 8);
    let val = val.add_to_x(5);
    dbg!(val);
}
```

I changed the return type of your method, and explicitly made `self.x` the last expression.  Then it works as you'd expect, saying that `val = 10`

Also note that I'm returning a copy of the field not a reference.  That's a more complicated question, and will almost-certainly require lifetimes.

[Link to Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=49dcb734d5d0462d96ea6000ad25e297)